# I am trying to make a substitution cipher for an assignment and we need a cipher.txt file that substitutes letters

Tags: c, encryption, caesar-cipher

[My cipher.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grGd6.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //ask the user what they want to encrypt or decrypt a string
    printf("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt a string? (e/d): ");
    char choice;
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    //if the user wants to encrypt, then use cipher.txt to encrypt the string
    if (choice == 'e')
    {
        //ask the user for the string they want to encrypt
        printf("Enter the string you want to encrypt: ");
        char string[100];
        scanf("%s", string);

        //open cipher.txt
        FILE* cipher;
        cipher = fopen("cipher.txt", "r");

        //read the cipher.txt file
        char cipherText[26];
        fscanf(cipher, "%s", cipherText);

        //close cipher.txt
        fclose(cipher);

        //encrypt the string
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (string[i] == '\0')
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z')
            {
                string[i] = cipherText[string[i] - 'a'];
            }
            else if (string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                string[i] = cipherText[string[i] - 'A'] - 32;
            }
        }

        //print the encrypted string
        printf("The encrypted string is: %s: ", string);



    }
    //if the user chooses decryption, then decrypt the string
    else if (choice == 'd')
    {
        //ask the user for the string they want to decrypt
        printf("Enter the string you want to decrypt: ");
        char string[100];
        scanf("%s", string);

        //open cipher.txt
        FILE* cipher;
        cipher = fopen("cipher.txt", "r");

        //read the cipher.txt file
        char cipherText[26];
        fscanf(cipher, "%s", cipherText);

        //close cipher.txt
        fclose(cipher);

        //decrypt the string
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (string[i] == '\0')
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z')
            {
                string[i] = cipherText[string[i] - 'a'];
            }
            else if (string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                string[i] = cipherText[string[i] - 'A'] - 32;
            }
        }

        //print the decrypted string
        printf("The decrypted string is: %s", string);

    }
}
```

I tried to open and use the Cipher.txt file to swap the letters and encrypt simple words like hello and be able to decrypt them as well by inputting the cipher text. The cipher.txt file is written as so to swap the letters:

H,X
E,P
L,R
O,Q

And I cannot figure out how to get my program to read the file and take swap the letters with that given file

Answer (score 1):

Code has at least these problems.

**No limit on input**

Code risks overflowing `cipherText[]`.  Instead, use a width limit which is 1 less than the size.

```
    char string[100];
    // scanf("%s", string);
    scanf("%99s", string);

    char cipherText[26];
    // fscanf(cipher, "%s", cipherText);
    fscanf(cipher, "%25s", cipherText);
```

**cipher.txt issues**

It is unclear concerning the contents of `cipher.txt`, but it appears to have 25 letter mappings [A-Z], but not 'O'.

I would expect cipher.txt to be 26 uppercase characters: `QWRST...A`.

cipher.txt file is dubious as it 1) does not have 26 mappings and 2) maps some letters to non-letters.

#2 makes it problematic to decipher if the original message contained  non-letters.

**`cipherText[]` too small**

To read a cipher from a text file with `fscanf(cipher, "%s", cipherText);` and use it to encode 26 letters, `cipherText[]` needs to be 27 to hold the 26 letter mappings and the *null character*.

```
    char cipherText[26+1];
    // fscanf(cipher, "%s", cipherText);
    fscanf(cipher, "%26s", cipherText);
```

**Wrong case mapping**

OP indicates the cipher has an uppercase mapping.  Then encoding needs to change:

```
        else if (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z')
        {
            //string[i] = cipherText[string[i] - 'a'];
            string[i] = cipherText[string[i] - 'a'] - 'A' + 'a';
        }
        else if (string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            // string[i] = cipherText[string[i] - 'A'] - 32;
            string[i] = cipherText[string[i] - 'A'];
        }
```

**Code decrypts incorrectly**

Looks like a repeat of encrypt code using same `"cipher.txt"` file.  Code needs to reverse the mapping, not simply apply it again.

**Perhaps other issues too**